# Message Window C++ Win32 class/example

Tags: c++, winapi, window, message

Is there a class/example application for a message-only window that is in C++ [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean exactly? <a href="http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1810.asp">This article</a> shows you how to make a C++ class that encapsulates a window and handles the window messages in an object-oriented manner. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall, the standard solution is to create a basic styleless window with a message pump as you normally would, but never call ShowWindow on it. This way you can receive and process the standard messages like WM_QUERYENDSESSION which are sent to all windows.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs for [CreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679(VS.85).aspx):

> hWndParent
>       [in] Handle to the parent or owner window of the window being created. To
>   create a child window or an owned
>   window, supply a valid window handle.
>   This parameter is optional for pop-up
>   windows.
>
> Windows 2000/XP: **To create a message-only window, supply HWND_MESSAGE or a 
>   handle to an existing message-only window**.

[Here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#N6Qhr5kJSgQ/WebCore/platform/win/SharedTimerWin.cpp&q=HWND_MESSAGE) is some code, from WebKit I think, that sets up a message-only window for timer events.

Here is an article that shows a (possibly overly) fancy way to create an invisible, message-only window: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c12689

Answer (score 0):

A message-only window is used when you need to process windows messages in a thread, but you don't actually want to display a window on the screen.

For example, if you want to use a Windows timer, but don't have an existing UI window you could latch on to.